# Design an abstract class right way in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Given an abstract class A having a function sumBill(int a, int b). Now assume that you have 3 or 4 class extending class A and implementing their version of sumBill. And in various locations in the code you are making calls to sumBill with integer parameters. 
Later on it is identified that the parameters need to be of type double rather than int. So now one has to go refactor all the places which make a call to sumBill to pass parameters of double data type. 
So the question is what could the developer had done better to avoid such a problem in the first place. 
Its a design pattern question.How to implement it in C#?

Comment: Simply posting your homework on SO won't do. Please show what **you** have done already and where you're having an issue.

Comment: seems you want [Generic Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx)

Comment: Just refactor it. Modern IDEs and tools should make that fairly easy. And read up on the `decimal` type if you're working with finances. Generics are useful if you want to reuse code for different types, but that's not the case here (you're not summing both integer and double bills, you decided all bills need to use double).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work:

```
abstract class A{
    public abstract T sumBill<T>(T t1, T t2);
}

class B : A {
    public override T sumBill<T>(T t1, T t2) { /* your implementation of B here */ }   
}
```

This "pattern" is called Generics. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx).

However making every member generic only because it *might* be needed in the future is overkill. You probably won´t ever actually need it ([YAGNI](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html)). In fact you cannot foresee those cases. You implement a software based on some requirement, if the requirement changes you´d change the software also.

Comment: It sounds like, at the time he wrote the method, he had no idea they would be changed to doubles. In that case, I don't think templating every method you write, just in case the type might have to change, is a great solution.

Comment: @Kindread sure that might be the case, we do not what what the TO knew at that point of time. Having said so its indeed not great to change every method to generic. But if you have to change it once more you may consider such a solution.

Comment: Plus templating so absolutely does not work in these cases. You can not write a sensible mathematical operation without having any idea of the base type.

Comment: @HimBromBeere. I would consider generics/templates if I reasonably expect that I have to realise the template with different types at the same time ( in 1 or multiple projects ), not so sure I would use it if I expect it will only ever be instantiated with 1 type. It feels like an unnecessary complication to the reader in that case. Please note I am not implying I am right and you are wrong, just trying to learn more about your point of view.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing. Stuff like that happens. You gather requirements as good as you can and sometimes that just is not enough.